# Instagram API - Getting larger profile picture

Tags: android, instagram

Is there any way to get a larger profile picture when using:

> String Instagram_Image = jsonObj.getJSONObject("user")
>                                       .getString("profile_picture");

For the Instagram API?

The returned image is only 150x150, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the url, you can see "/s150x150/", change that to "//" and voila.

before: https://igcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12230791_976808449024482_1070960303_a.jpg

after: https://igcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t51.2885-19//12230791_976808449024482_1070960303_a.jpg

Answer (score 2):

150x150 is the largest size you can get currently with Instagram API.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can replace '/s150x150' by '/s200x200' or '/s600x600' or '/s800x800' as well.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I haven't seen any documentation about it but I've tested with those values so I'm sharing here. Additionally, you can get the size of 640X640 as well :)

Comment: I would like add a note here that now this technique doesnot work anymore as instagram have changed the method.